# Abstract class with enum won't serialize correctly

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, enums, system.text.json

I have the following code in project `GameEngine`

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Domain;

namespace GameEngine;

public class Game
{
    public GameState State = new();

    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions JsonOptions = new()
    {
        IncludeFields = true,
        WriteIndented = true
    };

    private void SaveGame(string fileName)
    {
        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(State, JsonOptions);
        var exeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var workPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFilePath);
        if (workPath == null) return;
        var saveFilePath = Path.Combine(workPath, fileName) + ".json";
        File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, jsonString);
    }
}
```

And the following in project `Domain`

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Domain;

public class GameState
{
    public List<Player> PlayerList { get; set; } = default!;
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(AIPlayer), typeDiscriminator: "aiPlayer")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(HumanPlayer), typeDiscriminator: "humanPlayer")]
public abstract class Player
{
    public Hand Hand { get; } = new();
}

public class Hand
{
    public List<Card> CardList { get; set; } = [];
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(BlackCard), typeDiscriminator: "blackCard")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ColoredCard), typeDiscriminator: "coloredCard")]
public abstract class Card
{
    public Enum Value { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class BlackCard : Card
{
    public BlackCard(EBlackCardValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class ColoredCard : Card
{
    public ColoredCard(EColoredCardValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public enum EBlackCardValue
{
    Wild,
    Joker
}

public enum EColoredCardValue
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

How can I serialize an instance of `GameState` with the card values being properly serialized and deserialized? Currently I'm only getting the following

```
{
  "PlayerList": [
    {
      "$type": "humanPlayer",
      "Hand": {
        "CardList": [
          {
            "$type": "blackCard",
            "Value": {},
          },
          {
            "$type": "blackCard",
            "Value": {},
          },
...
```

I do not wish to switch to JSON.Net, only System.Text.Json

Comment: Well, do you actually set the values to non default values? Show that code.

Answer (score 1):

As your `Value` in the `Card` class is `Enum`, the JSON serializer will serialize the value as an object. And you will get an error when you add the `JsonStringEnumConverter` converter as it cannot serialize from the `Enum` type.

This can be resolved by declaring the `Value` property with your implemented enum instead of `System.Enum` in your derived classes as below:

```cs
public class BlackCard : Card
{   
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public EBlackCardValue Value { get; set; } = default!;

    public BlackCard(EBlackCardValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class ColoredCard : Card
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public EColoredCardValue Value { get; set; } = default!;

    public ColoredCard(EColoredCardValue value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This will hide the inherited member from the abstract class: `Card` but most probably this is not the answer you looking for.

In that case, I believe you need to implement a custom JSON Converter to serialize the `Enum` type:

```cs
public class CustomEnumConverter : JsonConverter<Enum>
{
    public override Enum Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                throw new Exception("Deserialize is not supported!");

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Enum value,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

And apply the `JsonConverter` attribute with implemented custom JSON converter on the above:

```cs
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(BlackCard), typeDiscriminator: "blackCard")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ColoredCard), typeDiscriminator: "coloredCard")]
public abstract class Card
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomEnumConverter))]
    public Enum Value { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

This will allow to serialize the `Enum` value as a string.

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m7llxR)